# Como obter os municípios limítrofes a partir de um geom_sf + ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapas

```
library(tidyverse)
library(geobr)
```

Suponha que eu esteja trabalhando com uma Unidade de Conservação. O Parque Nacional do Catimbau (PE), por exemplo.

Baixo os dados pelo pacote `geobr`

```
ucs<-read_conservation_units()


parna_catimbau <- ucs %>% 
  filter(str_detect(name_conservation_unit, "CATIMBAU"))
```

Depois ploto os limites do Parna:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = parna_catimbau, col = "red", fill = "orange", alpha = .3)+
  geom_sf_label(data = parna_catimbau, aes(label = name_conservation_unit))
```

[image: parna_catimbau]

O que eu gostaria de saber é se é possível através do `geom_sf(data= parna_catimbau)` obter os `geom_sf()` do municípios limítrofes.

Como eu sei que o Parna do Catimbau faz fronteira com o município de Sertânia e abarca os municípios de Buíque, Ibimirim e Tupanatinga eu consigo fazer manualmente:

Primeiro baixo os dados do Estado de Pernambuco:

```
pe<-read_municipality(code_muni = "PE")
```

Depois, crio um objeto com os referidos municípios:

```
municipios_uc<-pe %>% 
  filter(name_muni %in% c ("Buíque", "Ibimirim", "Sertânia", "Tupanatinga"))
```

E então junto tudo:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = municipios_uc)+
  geom_sf_text(data = municipios_uc, aes(label = name_muni))+
  geom_sf(data = parna_catimbau, col = "red", fill = "orange", alpha = .3)+
  geom_sf_label(data = parna_catimbau, aes(label = name_conservation_unit))
```

O resultado final é esse:

[image: parna_catimbau_com_municipios]

No entanto, como eu disse, gostaria de saber se há uma função que me permita plotar automaticamente os municípios que se relacionam com Parque Nacional do Catimbau.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*ggplot2* é apenas o que usa para plotar. O que precisa é de operações espaciais sobre os seus dados.

As últimas versões do *sf* têm implementadas as operações de conjunto do RGEOS. No seu caso, uma combinação de `st_touches` e `st_intersects` pode ser usada.

Entretanto, `st_touches` não irá funcionar se as bordas não coincidirem exatamente, o que é comum entre objetos geoespaciais de diferentes fontes. Para garantir o resultado, sugiro primeiro expandir levemente o polígono da unidade de conservação e depois calcular apenas as intersecções:

```
library(sf)

uc_ex <- st_buffer(parna_catimbau, .01)
inter <- st_intersects(uc_ex, pe)
```

O resultado é uma lista com os nomes (ou números) das linhas em que houve intersecção. Use-a para filtrar os municípios:

```
municipios_sel <- pe[unlist(inter), ]

municipios_sel
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 4 fields
#> geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -37.88221 ymin: -8.971401 xmax: -36.97082 ymax: -7.940434
#> CRS:            4674
#>     code_muni   name_muni code_state abbrev_state                           geom
#> 30    2602803      Buíque         26           PE MULTIPOLYGON (((-37.22367 -...
#> 73    2606606    Ibimirim         26           PE MULTIPOLYGON (((-37.39837 -...
#> 160   2614105    Sertânia         26           PE MULTIPOLYGON (((-37.53221 -...
#> 177   2615805 Tupanatinga         26           PE MULTIPOLYGON (((-37.36854 -...
```

Comment: Perfeito! Muito grato (mais uma vez)!